# JavaScript and CSS  referencing in master pages with authorization

Tags: .net, asp.net, master-pages, authorization

i am developing in asp.net and i use different JavaScript and CSS files.

- i have a master page "masterpage1"
- a folder admin
- in this folder i have a masterpage, called masterpageadmin which inherits from the masterpage1
- and all aspx files in the folder admin inherits from the masterpageadmin
- only the "admin" role can acess to the masterpageadmin and aspx files in the folder admin

My question:
how should i reference in my masterpage1 my JavaScript and CSS, so that the aspx files in the admin folder can use them.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET doesn't bother to protect any non-ASP.NET files. 
This includes CSS, JS, HTML, JPG, PNG, ...

In otherwords, one doesn't worry about protecting CSS and JS.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, but if i am referencing with <link href="jquery/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />, the aspx file cant find my css classes. The same with my jscripts. thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like the problem you are really having is a path problem. Play around with your path using `~/` (which specifies the application root) and `/` (which specifies the folder) until you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

When referencing a CSS or JS file in a mater page, It is usually necessary to use absolute paths instead of relative file path.

For example:

```
<link href="css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Is a relative path, the users browser will look for a folder called "css" in whatever directory the ASPX file is located in.

```
<link href="/css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Is an absolute path, the users browser will always look for a folder called "css" in the root of the web site, which may be different than the root of the web application.

Here is a great discussion on paths in ASP.Net
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/132081.aspx